# what's a reliable and fast defrag for Win2k8/IIS7 server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, defrag, defragmentation

We inherited several Win2k8/II7 that host about 40 websites each.

The drives are nearly full at all times, and while we're working on moving a lot of files to the Amazon S3, files are constantly being written and deleted. These are mostly images and dynamically written out asp.net pages.

The drives have not been defragmented for over a year and IO is becoming a real bottleneck.

Besides the build in defrag tool what are other good deframenting utilities are out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diskeeper is really good at doing what it does. I'm not so sure you're going to get the performance boost you're looking for though. A defragged hard drive helps with sequential data access (like what's common during a backup). With lots of "images and dynamically written out asp.net pages" you're going to have a lot of non-sequential reads and your performance won't go up much or at all. You're better off engineering a better solution.

Comment: we're doing that, but in the mean time you don't think it'll help at all?

Comment: Not really. Not with lots of small files. What's the advantage to having defragged small files? That head is still hopping around quite a bit to access all of the different (but not fragmented) files.

Answer (score 1):

Ninite.com includes Defraggler and Auslogics.

Answer (score 1):

Good free ones are [jkDefrag](http://www.kessels.nl/JkDefrag/) (old-er, GPL) and [myDefrag](http://www.mydefrag.com/) (freeware).